# Association with account after creating temporary account

Tags: support

Posting from a different PC to ask my first question on the English SE site I opted to use a temporary identity (varying items blocked from said PC) with the belief I could associate the question with my standard OpenId (Google) account when at my personal PC.

This does not seem to be the case. How can I associate the given question with my standard account which I am under now? They both are tied to the same email address however forcing the merge seems to be impossible?

- [Temp User](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5598/aaron)
- [Real User](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5612/aaron)

Note the reputation differences; as the images/name are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have access to the first computer, you can edit your profile to say "I am also user 5612, please merge me with that account" and flag for a mod.

Comment: I manually added my Google OpenId on the initial PC after the fact in hopes of having the ability to merge and now I can see no way of getting back to the earlier account. Flagged the initial question for mod attention...will see if that does it...

Comment: That worked....